# Need help my android app (http request) is working in an emulator but not on a physical galaxy S5

Tags: android, http, android-asynctask

The app works in android studio with the emulator and an xampp server on the same machine but when I try running it on the Galaxy S5 connected via usb and using my data package on the sim I get the following error in the logcat: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false, from what I can tell there is some kind of connection error and the array returned is a null set, this causes the app to crash. I tried the following connection urls and none worked: http://190.xxx.xx.xx/abcd/search.php, 190.xxx.xx.xx/abcd/search.php, http://190.xxx.xx.xx:80/abcd/search.php, 190.xxx.xx.xx:80/abcd/search.php

```
       protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];

        // Note Android reserved loopback address is 10.0.2.2
        // Testing server
        //String login_url = "http://10.0.2.2/ttsrp/search.php";
        // Live server
        String login_url = "http://190.xxx.xx.xx/abcd/search.php";
        Log.i("URL set:",login_url);

        if (type.equals("search")){
            try {
                Log.i("Branch :","Search String Accepted.");
                String search_key = params[1];
                //String password = params[2];
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("search_key", "UTF-8")+"="+
                        URLEncoder.encode(search_key, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);

                //Buffer Writer cleanup
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                String result = "";
                String line = "";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null)
                bufferedReader.close();{
                    result += line;
                }
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                Log.i("Information : ","Close Connection");
                return result;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.e("ERROR: ","Wrong or malformed URL.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        //alertDialog.show();

        ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.fp_list);


        if (result==null){
            Log.e("ERROR : ", "Null Dataset returned.");
        }else{
            Log.d("Result:", result);
        }


        JSONArray jarr = null;
        JSONObject jobj = null;
        try {
            jarr = new JSONArray(result);

            for (int i=0; i<(jarr.length()); i++){
                jobj = jarr.getJSONObject(i);

                int id = jobj.getInt("id");
                String off = jobj.getString("off");
                String act = jobj.getString("act");
                String ena = jobj.getString("ena");
                int fine = jobj.getInt("fine");
                int dem = jobj.getInt("dem");

                String lab = "acb " + act + " " + ena + " " +"123 " + dem;
                arrayList.add(lab);
                arrayList.add(off);
            }
            //Create Adapter
            ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(FixedPenalty.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
            //assign adapter to listview
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
         } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Is the Galaxy S5 connected to the same network as the computer when you do this?

Comment: No disconnected it from wifi

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, a low battery in a wireless mouse caused this code to accidentally move, closing the bufferreader prematurely.

```
 while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null)
            bufferedReader.close();{
                result += line;
            }
```

should be

```
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                    result += line;
                }
bufferedReader.close();
```

Still dont know why it still worked in the emulator though.